# Printing 2D array in C language using system ECHO command

Tags: c, echo

How do I execute the system command “echo” in a C program to print out all the elements in a 2D array? I tried it, but it didn't work.

Input:

```
char myarray[1][10] = {"Hello", "World"};
system("echo $myarray");
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello World
```

Currently I do not get any output whatsoever.

Update 1 (constraints):
I cannot allocate more memory – I can only use the myarray variable.
I may use any other scalar or pointer variables.

Comment: You can't. The shell process that runs `echo` does not have access to the array inside the C program. Well, I guess you could write C code that builds up an `echo` string that is then passed to `system`. But not sure that is what you want. Perhaps this is a case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to take a variable number of input strings as parameters.
Copy each of the strings to a char array within an array.
Execute the system command “echo” to print out all the copied strings

Comment: " I cannot allocate more memory – I can only use the myarray variable. I may use any other scalar or pointer variables." Why not? What's that nonsense requirement?

Comment: And please don't post a new nearly identical question, edit the question instead. I've closed this one as the new one was clearer, but in the future please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the whole command in a single string before calling `system`. Something like:

```
char myarray[2][10] = {"Hello", "World"};
//           ^ notice

char mycommand[42];
strcpy(mycommand, "echo \"");
strcat(mycommand, myarray[0]);
strcat(mycommand, " ");
strcat(mycommand, myarray[1]);
strcat(mycommand, "\"");

system(mycommand);
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I'm assuming this is on a Linux machine, not Windows!</sub>

The system command `echo` takes as a parameter what you want it to print out. So you'd think that

```
echo $myArray
```

would print out

```
$myArray
```

but it doesn't. The `$` means "Look up the following string in the list of environment variables and print that". And `myArray` isn't defined in your list of environment variables, so it prints out nothing. It *definitely* won't print out a variable inside your computer program!

If you changed the call to

```
system("echo $path");
```

you would get a long string printed out, listing a number of directories. That's your current `path`.

But none of that answers your problem. What you want to do is print out `Hello World` using the `echo` command. That means that you need to (effectively) call the `system()` function with the following argument:

```
system("echo Hello world");
```

The only way you can do that is to "construct" the string that you want it to print out, and then tell `system()` the complete string.

So you need something like the following:

```
#define NUMSTRINGS 2  // Note that there are 2 strings!

char myArray[NUMSTRINGS][10] = {"Hello", "world"};
char command[256] = "echo"; // Start command

int i;
for (i=0; i<NUMSTRINGS; ++i) {
    strcat(command, " ");        // Space separator
    strcat(command, myArray[i]); // Next string
} // for
system(command);
```

Comment: I just updated my question. I cannot use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, because `myarray` is a variable in C, and `$myarray` is an environment variable in the shell.  They have no relation to one another--just as "Reading, England" and "Reading the news" have no relation.

If you want to pass variables to the shell, you can try `setenv()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @user3754152 - Have you been banned from google?